# How to handle passwords and secrets in C# projects in Azure DevOps / TFS code repository

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, passwords, repository, secret-key

How should a DEV team handle passwords and secrets stored in C# projects.

We are using Visual Studio 2015 and Azure DevOps (mainly VSTS but sometimes git repos) as code repository .

We try (whenever we can) to store security data in separate config files and ignore these files in `.tfignore` / `.gitignore`.

From time to time someone forgets and the secret gets submitted. 
Sometimes, the passwords are stored inside unit tests and not deleted prior check in.

It is good if a developer notice immediately but sometimes we discover this several commits later.

I think I have seen somewhere (now cannot find it) that it is possible to decorate lines in the code that hold security information. This either warned the developer or even block the check in. Not sure if this was Visual Studio addin, Azure DevOps feature or something different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

1. Environment Variables: You can override your local app secrets with an environment variable of the same key name.
2. [Secret Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows#secret-manager): This tool stores app secrets separately to your project and can be shared across different projects. They are not checked in to source control. However note this is for development only as the contents are not encrypted. For production you can use a service like [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/).

For your Azure DevOps build and deployment pipelines you can use the secure file option under Pipelines > Library > Secure files. This uploads and encrypts the secrets file and makes them available to your pipelines via the [Download Secure File task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops). E.g:

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: mySecureFile
    inputs:
      secureFile: file-name-of-secure-file
```

Once downloaded you can use the `name` to reference it in other tasks using the `$(mySecureFile.secureFilePath)` variable.